# In a business network, how does each peer "get a copy of the ledger"?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Let's say we have companies A, B, C in a business network.

How do these companies each "get a copy of the ledger"?

Do they all have to download Hyperledger Fabric, set up a Kube cluster, and connect to it with a card that the original sponsor provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, sort-of. There are different ways of kicking things off. You might start with A ,B and C all forming a consortium, installing/deploying the Hyperledger Fabric software and creating and joining a channel that includes A, B and C at the outset.

They would all "get a copy of the ledger" for that channel by virtue of the fact that as transactions are processed, they would all be receiving the ordered transactions from the ordering service, and their respective peer nodes participating in that channel would update their respective copies of the ledger with those transactions.

New peers can be added to an org, and those would receive copies of the ledger via gossip from the other peers.

New organizations can be added to the channel after its creation, and they would also be caught-up via gossip and then by virtue of receiving ordered transactions from the ordering service, etc.

The [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/master/whatis.html) explains all of this.