# How to update ledger state when new Org/peer is added to Hyperledger Fabric Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying out the **Hyperledger Fabric v1.1 BYFN network** .

Suppose i want to add a new org/peer . The **first-network** sample provides a script file **eyfn.sh** to add a new org/peer .

Now say i have added a new Org/peers in the existing network . Will org3 have a new ledger or is the ledger state updated in org3 automatically with previous already existing data .

Where can i see this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, you'll find an understanding of the concepts (relationship of ledger to the peers in an Org) on this page -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/peers/peers.html (Ledgers and Chaincode).

The answer to the 'ledger catch-up' question is answered here -> [In a business network, how does each peer "get a copy of the ledger"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179451/in-a-business-network-how-does-each-peer-get-a-copy-of-the-ledger)