# Will the existing ledger (state + blockchain) also be shared with the new member to the channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the scenario of adding a new member (a new organization's peer) to existing channel, will the whole previous ledger (state + blockchain) also be duplicated on this new peer?
Or just the genesis/more recent reconfiguration block will be shared with the new member? As the [doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channels.html) below says,

When adding a new member to an existing channel, either this genesis block, or if applicable, a more recent reconfiguration block, is shared with the new member.

I found an answer in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179451/in-a-business-network-how-does-each-peer-get-a-copy-of-the-ledger),

New organizations can be added to the channel after its creation, and they would also be caught-up via gossip and then by virtue of receiving ordered transactions from the ordering service, etc.

But I haven't found it explicitly in the document, not sure whether it is correct or not...

Only found something related in the [Gossip protocol doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/gossip.html) :
Bring newly connected peers up to speed by allowing peer-to-peer state transfer update of ledger data.

I guess the case above also includes "new member/organization".
But not for sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a new member (organization) to a channel - all its peers are automatically synced either from the orderers themselves directly, or from other peers from different organizations (assuming you have anchor peers), or from both. 
All the ledger - the data blocks and config blocks are being synchronized and committed to the ledger.